# Unable to fix button alignment wrt container in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a piece of `html` code, where everything is fine except for the position of the button. It's very far away from the container. This is my code below:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="inp_field" style="background-color: rgb(127, 255, 202); padding: 5em 5em">
        <div class="container" style="background-color: rgb(250, 214, 116); width:25em;">
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="mySwitch" name="emp">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="mySwitch"><b id="tag">EmpName</b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="You can toggle the above button to choose between empname and PF no :))"  placeholder="Enter empname" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || event.charCode==32" >
                <label for="emp">Enter your name</label>
            </div>
            <label for="sel1" class="form-label"><b>Select period (YM - YM):</b></label>
                <div id="period">
                    <select class="form-select" id="sel1" name="sel1" style="width: 7em;"></select>
                    <b>-</b>
                    <select class="form-select" id="sel2" name="sel2" style="width: 7em;" disabled></select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checksupp" name="Check if supplementary bill is required" value="Check if supplementary bill is required">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checksupp">Check if supplementary bill is required</label>
                </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ms-2 d-flex align-items-start justify-content-start" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

The `button` with the id *submit* is very far away from the container (the reference image is uploaded below). I am not able to fix this. Please help me.

[image: I want the button to be in this position below the container in the center]

Comment: Where do you want the button to be? Do you want it to be under the Yellowish Container? or inside the Yellow Container

Comment: Below the yellow container and it should be in the center

Comment: Check my answer, it might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.container` from the `yellow` box and add padding,
Also, add `.flex-column` to the parent class to make it a column, right now your flex container is row-wise, make the parent div of the select elements a flex box with `justify-content-between` to create gap between the elements
And to make your select row wise

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Add flex-column class-->  
        <div class="container-fluid mt-1 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center" id="inp_field" style="background-color: rgb(127, 255, 202); padding: 5em 5em">
       <!-- Remove container class from this div and add padding -->
        <div class="p-4"style="background-color: rgb(250, 214, 116); width:25em;">
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="mySwitch" name="emp">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="mySwitch"><b id="tag">EmpName</b></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="You can toggle the above button to choose between empname and PF no :))"  placeholder="Enter empname" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || event.charCode==32" >
                <label for="emp">Enter your name</label>
            </div>
            <label for="sel1" class="form-label"><b>Select period (YM - YM):</b></label>
                <!-- Make it a flex box container-->
                <div id="period" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <select class="form-select" id="sel1" name="sel1" style="width: 7em;"></select>
                    <b>-</b>
                    <select class="form-select" id="sel2" name="sel2" style="width: 7em;" disabled></select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checksupp" name="Check if supplementary bill is required" value="Check if supplementary bill is required">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checksupp">Check if supplementary bill is required</label>
                </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ms-2 d-flex align-items-start justify-content-start" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now, the dropdowns  are vertically aligned. I want them as they were before horizontally

Comment: Check it now, it might work now

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a parent `grid` element, now you can arrange and style your elements as you wish.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid mt-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="inp_field" style="background-color: rgb(127, 255, 202); padding: 5em 5em">
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-column-gap: 2em">
      <div class="container" style="background-color: rgb(250, 214, 116); width:25em;">
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="mySwitch" name="emp">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="mySwitch"><b id="tag">EmpName</b></label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="You can toggle the above button to choose between empname and PF no :))" placeholder="Enter empname" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || event.charCode==32">
          <label for="emp">Enter your name</label>
        </div>
        <label for="sel1" class="form-label"><b>Select period (YM - YM):</b></label>
        <div id="period">
          <select class="form-select" id="sel1" name="sel1" style="width: 7em;"></select>
          <b>-</b>
          <select class="form-select" id="sel2" name="sel2" style="width: 7em;" disabled></select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checksupp" name="Check if supplementary bill is required" value="Check if supplementary bill is required">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="checksupp">Check if supplementary bill is required</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 80px; height: 40px; align-self: self-end" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want it outside the container (`<div>`) i.e., below the yellow container and it should be in the center of the screen

Comment: I updated my answer. Works for you now?

Comment: The `<select>` tags are vertically aligned now. This doesn't look good. The yellow container shouldn't be changed in any manner. Only the button should be below the container, in the center wrt the screen

Comment: I didn't change your other elements, just copy-pasted your html and added a surrounding element `<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-column-gap: 2em">` and rearranged the yellow container and the submit button into this element. Submit button minor styling: `<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 80px; height: 40px; align-self: self-end" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this, your button is outside of the main container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NOTA MEDIA</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid mt-1 align-items-center justify-content-center" id="inp_field" style="background-color: rgb(127, 255, 202); padding: 5em 5em">
            <div class="container" style="background-color: rgb(250, 214, 116); width:25em;">
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="mySwitch" name="emp">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="mySwitch"><b id="tag">EmpName</b></label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="You can toggle the above button to choose between empname and PF no :))"  placeholder="Enter empname" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                    event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || event.charCode==32" >
                    <label for="emp">Enter your name</label>
                </div>
                <label for="sel1" class="form-label"><b>Select period (YM - YM):</b></label>
                <div id="period">
                    <select class="form-select" id="sel1" name="sel1" style="width: 7em;"></select>
                    <b>-</b>
                    <select class="form-select" id="sel2" name="sel2" style="width: 7em;" disabled></select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checksupp" name="Check if supplementary bill is required" value="Check if supplementary bill is required">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="checksupp">Check if supplementary bill is required</label>
                </div>
               
            </div>
            <div class="row align-items-center mb-2">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ms-2 align-items-start" type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want it outside the container, not inside. And  it should be aligned at the center

Comment: Check it now Bro !